# Demonstrating back EMF on an inductor in LTSpice

Tags: spice, ltspice, back-emf

I'm trying to demonstrate back EMF on an inductor in LTSPice with this model:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16979265/Draft2.asc

I'm expecting the voltage on the inductor to have a negative spike on the falling edge but it doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong here?:

[image: LTSpice simulation trying to demonstrate back EMF on an inductor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emmiter-base voltage is always greater than \$V_{\gamma}\$ (0.6 V) by a lot, in practice the transistor would be destroyed. Take a look at the base current and you will realize.

Answer (score 1):

If you pick a transistor instead of going for the generic PNP you'll see the spike, but the transistor's collector current may not be realizable in the real world.

As an aside, if you configure LTspice to plot thick lines it makes the plot much easier to view here.

For example:

[image]